# Queue implementation

Tags: queue, firebird

What is the best way to implement fast queue where multiple users try to access to about 100 000 records.  Only one user can get one unique row. Now im using sql database (firebird) but there is a lot of problems deadlocks / high database load.

Comment: Does "access" mean read or write?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, deadlocks are caused by bad transaction logic.

In general, the transactions have to be short (the shorter the better).

You can start by reading some doc:

- [A not-so-very technical discussion of Multi Version Concurrency Control](https://firebirdsql.org/en/multi-version-concurrency-control/)
- [Firebird for the Database Expert: Episode 4 - OAT, OIT, & Sweep](https://web.archive.org/web/20231004130607/https://ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design/doc_21)